# How can I customize the "jumping" from the Eclipse problems view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to customize the way double clicking works in the ProblemsView for my RCP application. Right now, the resource is set to a file and the location is set to a line number. That works great for a text-based editor, but I am creating a multipage form based editor.

How can I change the behavior of the ProblemsView so that I can get in the middle of the double clicking and the jumping and interpret the location (or some other marker attribute) so that my form editor will respond in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an IGotoMarker adapter for your editor, and then handle it how you will.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ide/IGotoMarker.html

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen any mention of this in all the googling I did so far.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials or more documentation on this? I'm having trouble finding

Comment: You'll see it implemented in the text editor class hierarchy. It would be similar for your editor until the platform actually calls the adapter.